# SQL query assistance (i am trying to learn)

Tags: sql

i need help with this

i have table world(name, continent, capital) and i dont know how to do this:

1. Find the country where the capital is the country plus "City".
2. Find the countries that have two "o" characters separated by two others.
3. Find the countries that have three or more a in the name.
4. Find the capital and the name where the capital is an extension of name of the country.

Thanks a lot  blush

Comment: We wont do your homework! SELECT, WHERE, LIKE etc is a good start!

Comment: omg... it is not homework... it is from sqlzoo.net and i do a lot practice... but dont know how to do this... so thank u for help!!! u are really helpfull

Comment: The more effort you show, the better answers you'll get! For example add table definitions, sample data, expected result, and also the queries you've tried - and describe what's wrong with them etc.

Comment: so first task... i dont know how to add the city in name... i tried to do "where world.name+city=world.capital" it didnt work... i dont know how to include it,

Comment: second and third task i dont know function if any exists...

Comment: Which dmbs product are you using? (Tag you question...) Some products have their own versions instead of the standard string handling functions...

Comment: i am practising here... http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_names

Comment: i didnt use sql before... i am just new who want to get better

Comment: for the first one you can use concat function `FROM world
 WHERE capital = concat(name,' City')`

Comment: Second question hint `%` wilcard represent more than one charachter where `_` represent a single charachter while using like

Answer (score 1):

On the page with your questions, your 1st question here is number 12 there.  This is what they give you to start with:

```
SELECT name, concat(name, 'town')
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE '%ina%'
```

Also, right above the textarea, they mention `the concat function`.  For question 12, where the capital is the name of the country plus the word "City", your where clause would be:

```
where capital = concat(name, ' City')
```

Note the leading space before the word City.   That should get you going on the rest of them.

Comment: thanks a lot :) i may ask u one another thing, u dont know how can i include into querry for example if i want to find 3 same letters in word -(Find the countries that have three or more "a" in the name).

Answer (score 0):

```
1. SELECT name FROM world WHERE capital=concat(name,' city');

2. SELECT name FROM world WHERE name LIKE '%o__o%';

4. SELECT name,mid(capital,LENGTH(name)+1) rep
         FROM world
             WHERE capital LIKE concat(name,'_%');

   one more method for ques number 4 using REPLACE SQL FUNCTION: OR

  SELECT name,replace(capital,name,'') rep
            FROM world
                  WHERE capital LIKE concat(name,'_%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.SELECT name FROM world WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '%','City');

2.SELECT name FROM world WHERE name LIKE '%o__o%';

3.SELECT name FROM world WHERE name LIKE '%a%a%a%';

4.SELECT name, capital FROM world WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '_%');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
SELECT 
    name, capital
FROM
    world
WHERE
    capital LIKE concat('%', name, '%') OR capital LIKE concat('%', name, '%')
```

Does anyone have a more eloquent way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Find the country where the capital is the country plus "City".

```sql
    1. SELECT

    2. Name

    3. FROM world

    4. WHERE capital LIKE ‘%City’;
```

This is how I found the answer and I know this is not the correct way. I basically had to look up the correct way of doing it because my gut was telling me that I used a short cut!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).